# Вводная конструкция "по крайней мере"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Вот фраза: "*Все было хорошо. По крайне мере() у меня*". Нужна ли здесь запятая? Если интонационно, то, скорее всего, не нужна. А по правилу нужна: "Во всяком случае, у меня".  Можно еще сказать: "Как минимум, у меня". Это означает "самое меньшее". И начинается путаница. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

> "Все было хорошо. По крайне мере() у меня". Нужна ли здесь запятая?
>   Если интонационно, то, скорее всего, не нужна. А по правилу нужна...

Действительно какая-то путаница. Во всяком случае у Вас. Все упомянутые Вами выражения ("по крайней мере", "во всяком случае", "как минимум", "самое меньшее") зачастую не являются вводными. По воле автора их можно считать вводными и выделять запятыми в том случае, когда они выражают субъективное мнение и выделяются интонационно. Но Вы сами признаёте, что интонационного выделения здесь нет. Следовательно, это не вводная конструкция.

Приведу часть соответствующей статьи из "Словаря вводных слов..." O.A. Остроумовой и О.Д. Фрамполь.

> **ПО КРАЙНЕЙ МЕРЕ, устар. ПО КРАЙНОСТИ,** частица. Неустойчиво вводное, решение об обособлении принимает автор: **по крайней мере**
>   обособляется в функции вводного для выражения субъективного отношения
>   к какому-либо факту (= *между прочим*, *хочу заметить*), интонационно
>   выделяется; не обособляется в функции частицы (= *хотя бы*),
>   интонационно не выделяется.
>
> Ср.: *Так, **по крайней мере**, (= хочу заметить) казалось, потому что
>   она дышала в микрофон*  (А.Алексин). *Так по крайней мере (= хотя бы)
>   казалось, потому что она дышала в микрофон.*
>
> Частица **по крайней мере** обычно стоит непосредственно перед
>   словами, с которым связана по смыслу: ***По крайней мере*** так
>   казалось, потому что она дышала в микрофон.

Вот ещё цитата из того же словаря, которая может быть полезна.

> Даже по контексту невозможно различить, в какой функции употреблено то
>   или иное слово: все зависит от желания автора — либо подчеркнуть свою
>   субъективность, либо использовать слово в свойственной ему функции.
>   Например: *по крайней мере, в  известном смысле, действительно, между
>   тем, во всяком случае, на первый взгляд, так или иначе.*

Answer (score 1):

**Все было хорошо. По крайней мере у менЯ.**

**Но:  Все было хорошо.  У менЯ, по крайней мере.**

В то же время обособление этих выражений часто считается факультативным, решение может принимать автор.

Пояснение

**1) Эта тема в справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации"**  раскрывается примерно так.

Если наречие ***по крайней мере*** имеет значение "как минимум", то оно не обособляется, например: Нужно владеть  хотя бы одним иностранным языком **по крайней мере (= как минимум).**

Но сочетания ***по крайней мере, во всяком случае*** могут выражать уверенность в чем-то, хотя и ограниченную какими-то пределами: **У меня, по крайней мере**... (а за всех я не могу сказать).

Значение уверенности выражают вводные слова, которые надо бы обособлять. Но в художественной литературе вполне уважаемые авторы эти сочетания часто не обособляют, например: ...  **я по крайней мере** такой доброте никакой цены не придаю! И. Тургенев, Новь).

2) **Как тут разобраться?**  Если семантика эту задачу решить не помогает, то надо использовать интонационно-структурный анализ.

Необособленное наречие должно вписываться в структуру основного предложения, причем на него не должно падать логическое ударение. Тогда его можно не обособлять:

У меня **по крайней мере** есть мУж, которого я люблю. [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)] Если я поступал неискренно, то у меня **по крайней мере** было оправдАние. [К. М. Станюкович.  (1879)] **По крайней мере** у менЯ было именно такое ощущение. [Анна Ларина (Бухарина). Незабываемое (1986-1990)]

Обособление делается обычно в том случае, если ударение падает на предшествующие слова:

ТепЕрь у меня, **по крайней мере,** есть опыт, и мы еще потягаемся. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Село Степанчиково и его обитатели (1859)]

Примеры